# Google Maps - Clustering by type markers

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps, android-maps-extensions

Question about GoogleMap from Google Maps API Android v2. I use clustering library [android-maps-ekstensions](https://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/). The map markers are of different types. The problem that the markers of different types are clustered together. Is it possible to cluster the markers by type in different clusters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible as of version 1.3.1 of the library.

This is already on the TODO list, so you may want to star [Issue 10](http://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/issues/detail?id=10) to be notified of the progress.

**Edit:**

This is available as of version 1.5 via a simple call:

```
theMarker.setClusterGroup(777);
```

The default group is `0` and only `Marker`s with the same group are clustered together, so if you assign some `int` value to every `Marker` type, you will be good.